# Advanced SQL Query Struggles

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, greatest-n-per-group

so basically the issue I am having at the moment is I cannot work out how to do an advanced JOIN query in SQL Server.

I have the following tables:

- incidents
- consequences
- incident_consequence (join)
- severities

My query needs to pull each incident record from the database and determine its severity which is done via the consequences that are associated with the incident (in the join table incident_consequence). Each consequence record has a severity foreign key associated with it. Once I have all the consequences associated to the incident I need to only return the one that has the highest severity.level integer value.

So as you might be seeing here, I need to join the incident_consequences.incident_id to the incidents.id table for all the relationships and from there join the incident_consequence.consequence_id to consequences.id then the severity to the consequences.severity, etc, etc.

I am having a lot of trouble doing this and am hoping a smart person that knows SQL really well will be able to help me out with this query.

Here is what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.incidents.id, MAX(severities1.[level]) AS severities
FROM dbo.incidents
INNER JOIN dbo.incident_consequence
  ON dbo.incidents.id = dbo.incident_consequence.incident_id
INNER JOIN dbo.consequences
  ON dbo.incident_consequence.consequence_id = dbo.consequences.id
INNER JOIN dbo.severities AS severities1
  ON dbo.consequences.severity = severities1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.severities AS severities2
  ON severities1.id = severities2.id AND severities1.[level] < severities2.[level]
WHERE (severities2.id IS NULL)
GROUP BY dbo.incidents.id, severities1.[level]
```

[image: sql join visual]

This returns:

[image: result of my join query]

What I need is:

[image]

Really appreciate any help I can get with this one!

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: What about if several consequences all tie for the top severity?

Comment: Then it won't matter which consequence it is, we will only need one result for the return to say that this is the severity for the incident. Which in the case of say 5, 5, 5 we just need the one 5 to assign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, I dont see why you even need to have the second join to severities.

Rather try something like

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
    dbo.incidents.id, 
    MAX(severities1.[level]) AS severities
FROM    dbo.incidents INNER JOIN 
    dbo.incident_consequence ON dbo.incidents.id = dbo.incident_consequence.incident_id INNER JOIN 
    dbo.consequences ON dbo.incident_consequence.consequence_id = dbo.consequences.id INNER JOIN 
    dbo.severities AS severities1 ON dbo.consequences.severity = severities1.id 
GROUP BY dbo.incidents.id
```

Comment: This is working exactly how I need it! You are right, I guess I got a bit mixed up in the JOIN's, I was so close haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `order by severity.level desc` and [`TOP 1`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) to return just the most severe row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.incidents.id, severities1.[level] AS severities
FROM dbo.incidents
INNER JOIN dbo.incident_consequence
  ON dbo.incidents.id = dbo.incident_consequence.incident_id
INNER JOIN dbo.consequences
  ON dbo.incident_consequence.consequence_id = dbo.consequences.id
INNER JOIN dbo.severities AS severities1
  ON dbo.consequences.severity = severities1.id
WHERE (severities2.id IS NULL)
ORDER BY severities1.[level] DESC
```

I removed the unnecessary DISTINCT, JOIN, MAX() and GROUP BY.

I left in your aliases, but they are unconventionally long - you would improve readability by making them shorter.

Comment: Is sorting faster than using a MAX?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is only working for 1 incident record (which has the highest severity), I need it to be for individual unique incidents in the join table. astanders query is working this way. Really appreciate you taking the time to help out though, thanks heaps.